# Difference between jQuery's mouseenter-mouseleave vs hover events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, difference

Are there any differences between the following code snippet?

**Snippet 1:**

```
$("textarea").mouseenter(function() {
    alert("Hello mouseenter!");
});

$("textarea").mouseleave(function() {
    alert("Hello mouseleave!");
});
```

**Snippet 2:**

```
$("textarea").hover(function() {
    alert("Hello mouseenter!");
}, function() {
    alert("Hello mouseleave!");
});
```

I've checked the above code snippet in Chrome and Firefox, but both snippets were behaved identically. However, I wanted to make sure as, Is there any difference between mouseenter-mouseleave and hover events?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between them... the hover() method registers the mouseenter and mouseleave handlers internally....

hover - code

```
hover: function( fnOver, fnOut ) {
    return this.mouseenter( fnOver ).mouseleave( fnOut || fnOver );
}
```

The only difference is if you want make use of event delegation, in that scenario you cann't use `.hover()`

Answer (score 2):

jQuery docs say:

> Calling $( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut ) is shorthand for:
>
> 1 $( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );

Answer (score 2):

Hover uses `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

The different one is `mouseover` and `mouseout`. `enter/leave` are not native events, they're a subset of `over/out` events.

`over/out` events also happen if you move from a parent into onto a child; you get a `mouseout`, and a `mouseover` when you move back. This is not good for hovers since you want the hover to apply to the element and it's children.

Answer (score 2):

Using the hover function will shoot the event twice and it will act for both mouse in and mouse out,
eg

```
$("#xyz").hover(function (e) {
            alert("In hover function ");
});
```

This will trigger the alert twice, once when you take your mouse on xyz element and once when you will take your mouse away from xyz. This may cause some trouble in your code, where as in mouseienter mouseleave event you can plan the event accordingly

Comment: ...unless you use the two-argument version, which takes on function for mouse in and one function for mouse out.

Answer (score 1):

Hover doesnot fire event for the children whereas mouseenter and mouseleave does.